# How to remove duplicated rows from a list in R

Tags: r

I created a list containing ingredients for a recipe, but somehow after scraping the data from the web the ingredients are always shown 2 times.

How do I remove the duplication from the listed items?

This is the list of ingredients I get:

```r
$Hozzávalók
[1] " 4 - 6 db kaffírlime-levél"     " 1 nagy csokor friss koriander" " 2 - 3 szál citromnád"         
[4] " 2 hüvelyknyi gyömbér"          " 3 gerezd fokhagyma"            " 2 szál újhagyma"              
[7] " 2 - 3 db zöld chili"           " 4 ek olívaolaj"                " 1 db lime leve"               
[10] " 170 g brokkoli"                " 4 - 5 fej sonkahagyma"         " 125 g zöldbab"                
[13] " 150 g cukkini"                 " 6 - 8 ek olaj"                 " 150 g cukorborsó"             
[16] " 500 ml zöldségalaplé"          " 1 konzerv kókusztej"           " 1 - 2 ek szójaszósz (világos)"
[19] "  só"                           " 100 g barna simeji gomba"      " 100 g simeji gomba"           
[22] "  ½ - 1 ek kukoricakeményítő"   " 1 db lime"                     "  rizstészta vagy jázmin rizs" 
[25] "  friss koriander"              "  friss chili"                  " 4 - 6 db kaffírlime-levél"    
[28] " 1 nagy csokor friss koriander" " 2 - 3 szál citromnád"          " 2 hüvelyknyi gyömbér"         
[31] " 3 gerezd fokhagyma"            " 2 szál újhagyma"               " 2 - 3 db zöld chili"          
[34] " 4 ek olívaolaj"                " 1 db lime leve"                " 170 g brokkoli"               
[37] " 4 - 5 fej sonkahagyma"         " 125 g zöldbab"                 " 150 g cukkini"                
[40] " 6 - 8 ek olaj"                 " 150 g cukorborsó"              " 500 ml zöldségalaplé"         
[43] " 1 konzerv kókusztej"           " 1 - 2 ek szójaszósz (világos)" "  só"                          
[46] " 100 g barna simeji gomba"      " 100 g simeji gomba"            "  ½ - 1 ek kukoricakeményítő"  
[49] " 1 db lime"                     "  rizstészta vagy jázmin rizs"  "  friss koriander"             
[52] "  friss chili"
```

And this is the codes I used:

```r
    streetkitchen <- function(url){
    h <- read_html(url)
    nev <- h %>% html_node(".entry-head-mobile .entry-title") %>% html_text()
    hozzavalok <- h %>% html_nodes("dd") %>% html_text() %>% !duplicated()
    recept <- h %>% html_nodes(".the-content-div p") %>% html_text()
    return(list(Név = nev, Hozzávalók = hozzavalok, Recept = recept))
    }
```

I tried to use the function `distinct()`  but it only works on data frames.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`unique` might be the function you're looking for:

```
unique(streetkitchen$Hozzávalók)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post suggests that you do have a dataframe (cf. the use of `$`). To remove duplicated **rows** from the dataframe, you can use `duplicated`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Hozzávalók = c(" 4 - 6 db kaffírlime-levél"," 1 nagy csokor friss koriander", " 2 - 3 szál citromnád", " 1 nagy csokor friss koriander"),
  SomeOtherVar = c(1,2,1,3)
)
df
                      Hozzávalók SomeOtherVar
1      4 - 6 db kaffírlime-levél            1
2  1 nagy csokor friss koriander            2
3           2 - 3 szál citromnád            1
4  1 nagy csokor friss koriander            3 # duplicated `Hozzávalók` value
```

Solution:

```
df[!duplicated(df$Hozzávalók),]
```

Result:

```
                      Hozzávalók SomeOtherVar
1      4 - 6 db kaffírlime-levél            1
2  1 nagy csokor friss koriander            2
3           2 - 3 szál citromnád            1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using `duplicated` is that only the first value of the other variable is kept, and this may not be what you want. You can group by and summarize to explicitly state how to calculate the other variable, e.g., using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(Hozzávalók) %>% summarise(SomeOtherVar = min(SomeOtherVar))
```